# I don't have access to variable

Tags: node.js, variables, express

It's my first question.

So, I'm using NodeJS + Express.

Here's my code:

```
request(urlPrice, function(err, resp, body){
    priceInfo = JSON.parse(body),
    medianPrice = priceInfo.median_price,
    changePrice = medianPrice.replace(',','.'),
    finallyPrice = parseFloat(changePrice).toFixed(2);
});

console.log(finallyPrice);
```

What can I do? Because, in `console.log()` the `finallyPrice` variable is `undefined`.

Please, help me.

Comment: Log priceInfo and post your json please.

Comment: Scope of variable should be checked.

Comment: Not sure if I agree that this is a duplicate question. The nuances of using NodeJS and Express and passing back information returned from a route is not the same thing as returning async data in regular Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the variables are set only in the request callback handler

```
request(urlPrice, function(err, resp, body){
    priceInfo = JSON.parse(body),
    medianPrice = priceInfo.median_price,
    changePrice = medianPrice.replace(',','.'),
    finallyPrice = parseFloat(changePrice).toFixed(2);
    console.log(finallyPrice);
});
```

Comment: Yes I know this work. But I need to use finallyPrice variable outside a request. Your solution works and I have context from json. I want to use finallyPrice variable outside a request then this don't work.I want to repair this and i don't have an idea how.

Comment: What do you mean by outside the request. you mean another request? Since its a web application, I am assuming you are only dealing with requests.

Comment: Thanks for help, it was synchronous web request.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you want access to the finallyPrice variable outside the actual request portion of your app.

To do this, you will have to `export` your objects so that they can be accessed outside the scope of the function they are defined in. This is how to pass variables back and forth in Node: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports. For a beginner post explaining how this all works, you may want to check out this: http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/